# The difference between int* ptr; and int *ptr; C++ pointers

Tags: c++

What is the difference between `int* ptr;` and `int *ptr;`?

I am doing a C++ linked list project, and I wish to know the difference between the two statements above.

Comment: No difference whatsoever, they are treated exactly the same.  Whitespace between tokens is ignored.

Comment: The only difference is the whitespace.  You forgot a version: `int * ptr;`.

Comment: Whitespace doesn't matter in C++. As long as tokens are separated properly you can have any amount of whitespace and it won't affect your program behavior.

Comment: hmm that is weird. When doing my c++ project an error message was thrown when i used something similiar to  "int *ptr" and not "int* ptr" this is not the exact code so there may lie my issue. Thank you for the quick responses.

Comment: You can even have `int` and `*` and `ptr` and `;` on separate lines.